# Example of a set that is $F_\sigma$ but not $G_\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Can anyone give me an example? My textbook offers a hint to let be a denumerable set that is  dense, although it doesn't say dense in what.

Comment: In what? In a complete metric space (or indeed any Baire space), such as the real numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of rational numbers in the reals.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Bbb Q=\{q_n:n\in \Bbb N\}.$ Let $F=\{O_n\}$ be a family of open subsets of $\Bbb R$ such that $\cap F\supset \Bbb Q.$  Let $G=\{O_n\backslash \{q_n\}:n\in \Bbb N\}.$ By the Baire Category Theorem, $\cap G$ is dense in $\Bbb R.$

So $(\cap F)\backslash \Bbb Q=\cap G\ne \emptyset.$ So $\cap F\ne \Bbb Q.$

So $\Bbb Q$ is not a $G_{\delta}$ subset of $\Bbb R.$ But $\Bbb Q$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ subset of $\Bbb R$ because $\Bbb Q=\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}\{q_n\}.$

If $S$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ and $S$ is a $G_{\delta}$ subset of $\Bbb R$ then by the above technique, $S$ is uncountable. So any countable dense subset of $\Bbb R$ is $F_{\sigma}$ but not $G_{\delta}.$

Comment: If $S$ is a dense $G_{\delta}$ subset of $\Bbb  R$ then, regardless of the Continuum Hypothesis, the cardinal of $S$ is the cardinal of $\Bbb R.$  But that is another story.

Answer (score 0):

Your text sounds like Stein's Real Analysis.

They want you to use the Baire Category Theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) with $\mathbb{Q}$. Indeed, as $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, it is a $F_{\sigma}$. Now we argue by contradiction to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a $G_{\delta}$. Indeed, suppose for contradiction that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a $G_{\delta}$. Then there exists open sets $\alpha_i$ such that $\mathbb{Q} = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha_i$.

Now let $\{Q_i: Q_i \in \mathbb{Q}, i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be an explicit enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$ and consider $ A_{k} : =(-\infty, Q_k) \cup (Q_k, \infty)$, then $\overline{A_k} = \mathbb{R}$, so we see $\overline{\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k} =\mathbb{R}$. So by Baire Category Theory, one sees that $\overline{\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \cap \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha_k} = \mathbb{R}$, but $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \cap \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha_k = \mathbb{Q} \cap \mathbb{Q}^c = \emptyset$, so we have $\overline{\emptyset} = \mathbb{R}$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a $G_{\delta}$.

Comment: $\overline{\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \cap \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}$ ?? This confuses me

Comment: I assume you meant $\overline{\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \cap \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_k,b_k)}$. It follows from Baire Categroy Theorem, which states that "A Baire space($\mathbb{R}$ is one) is a topological space with the following property: for each countable collection of open dense sets ${\displaystyle \{U_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty }}$, their intersection ${\displaystyle \textstyle \bigcap _{n=1}^{\infty }U_{n}}$ is dense."

Comment: A $G_{\delta}$ set is not necessarily equal to  the intersection $\cap_{i\in \Bbb N}(a_i,b_i)$ of a sequence of open intervals. But your idea is correct.... I think it would be clearer if you said $A_k=\Bbb R$ \ $\{q_k\}$  where $\Bbb Q=\{q_k: k\in \Bbb N\}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes you're right. I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: $G_{\delta}$ subsets of $\Bbb R$ have some interesting properties. E.g. if $S \subset \Bbb R$ then $S$ is $G_{\delta}$  iff ...(1) there is a complete metric for the sub$space $  $ S  $...(2) iff there exists $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ such that the set of points where $ f$ is continuous is exactly $S.$